# Angular 2: Implementing http service for delete

Tags: angularjs, http, service

I am trying to write a service for deleting from my external db and I keep seeing this error:

> The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly. Type
>   argument candidate 'Response' is not a valid type argument because it
>   is not a supertype of candidate 'Response'. Types of property 'type'
>   are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type
>   'ResponseType'.

^ and this error highlights the line:

```
return this.http.delete(`${this.base_url}/${id}`)
```

Here is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CheckIn } from './check-in';
import { Headers, RequestOptions, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()

export class CheckInService {

  private base_url = "http://localhost:3000/";

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  delete(id:string): Observable<CheckIn[]> {

    return this.http.delete(`${this.base_url}/${id}`)
                    .map((res:Response) => res.json()) .json() on the response to return data
                     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); 
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample code. I think problem is with the way you are accepting your response.

**Main Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {CheckInService} from "../shared/checkin.service";
@Component({
 selector: "test",
 templateUrl: "./test.html",
 styleUrls: ["./test.css"]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{

dataMap:any;
dataDeleteMap:any;
constructor(public dataMapService:CheckInService) {
    this.dataMapService=dataMapService;
}
ngOnInit(){}

  deleteField(id:string){
    this.dataMapService.deleteField(id).subscribe(jsonData=>{
    this.dataDeleteMap=jsonData;
  }); 
 }
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable ,OnInit,OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CheckInService {

data:any;
baseUrl:string='http://localhost:3000/';

constructor(public http:Http) { 
}

 deleteField(id:string):Observable<Response>{
   return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
   .map(result=>result.json());
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but I'm still not sure what `t` is supposed to be when I make the call to `deleteField()`

Comment: it was a mistake. `t` is not needed now you can try the code.